# Search for a substring in a text file and save to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to batch scripting in Windows and want to accomplish the following:

1. Search a text file (log.txt)
2. On line 8, grab the second number and save to a variable.

```
RXP:            3.2.2e (Feb 13 2002)
                rxp     sched   distr   policy  servers vifs    acache  aFNAT
                1       1       1       10      8       1       1       0
                kern    trace   log     schaddr
                1       0       3       xx.xx.xx.xxx

Scheduler:      opens   hits    cpuload errors  retries time
                15      426585  0       0       0       873431895
```

I want to save the number 426585 to a variable that I can use later.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
for /f "skip=7 tokens=2 delims= " %%l in (d:\thing.txt) do set HITS=%%l
echo %HITS%
```

Assuming the file is always 8 lines long and never any longer, and that hits is always the second column in the line. If it's longer you'll need more logic to ignore subsequent lines.

Edit: This should be able to to deal with more lines in the file that need ignoring:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "skip=7 tokens=2 delims= " %%l in (d:\thing.txt) do (
    if !FOUND! neq 1 (
        set HITS=%%l
        set FOUND=1
    )
)
echo %HITS%
```

PS. You could do it in PowerShell with

```
$hits = [Int](gc D:\thing.txt)[7].Split(' ', [StringSplitOptions]'RemoveEmptyEntries')[1]
write $hits
```

Edit: The PowerShell version doesn't need changing to ignore more lines.

Comment: Actually there is more than 8 lines in the file, so I would need to ignore the remaining lines as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Powershell due to restricted access on my work machine. So a way to exclude lines in .bat would be appreciated.